# Webscraping from word hippo

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a query regarding word scraping from word hippo. I am new to Beautiful Soup and don't how to get this list of words (described below)

I am trying to get all the synonyms under the following sections of the page (Even those synonyms below the 'more' button.

Section 1

[image]

Section 2

[image]

```
#My code.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/guard.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# select only first '<section class="synonyms-container....'
synonyms = soup.select('.MainContentContainer > section > .synonyms-container a')
print ('synonyms for: Guard')
for synonym in synonyms:
            print (synonym.text)
```

Please help extract a list of these words.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words is in `.relatedwords` class container, to get the first and second section loop it twice.

```
synonyms = soup.select('.relatedwords')
for i in range(0, 2):
    print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
    print (synonyms[i].text)
```

if you want to store each word as list use `synonyms[i].split("\n")`

Comment: Thank you @uingtea for helping with this. I managed to get the synonyms for both blocks .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/guard.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

synonyms = [
    a.getText() for a in soup.select_one('div.relatedwords').find_all("a")
]

for synonym in synonyms:
    print(synonym)
```

Output:

```
guardian
custodian
warden
keeper
sentry
escort
lookout
watch
minder
protector
... and more
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @baduker for helping me with this. I managed to get the First block of synonyms with this. How do I amend this code to get the second block? Thanks in advance.